# Set IE Driver Log level as TRACE which opens through RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I want to set log level as TRACE to IE Driver which opens through RemoteWebDriver. Using following code snippet to open IE through RemoteWebDriver:

```
String remote_address = "http://<ip address of Remote m/c>:4444/wd/hub";
URL remote_url = new URL(remote_address);
dc = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
wbdv = new RemoteWebDriver(remote_url, dc);
```

Please help if anyone knows how to add log level as TRACE to IE runs through RemoteWebDriver.